# Состав слова "Поднебесная"

Tags: морфология

ПОДНЕБЕСНАЯ. В тренировочной тетради на печатной основе (авт. Узорова и Нефёдова) в слове "поднебесная" указан корень небес, в словообразовательном словаре (В.И. Николаев) корень - неб. Помогите разобраться. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Некоторые рассматривают ЕС как наращение, или словоизменительный (формообразовательный) аффикс. -ес- служит для образования множественного числа и других форм. Так что на школьном уровне этот аффикс вполне можно вносить в корень.